# Compiling a java program

Tags: java, makefile

I'm trying to compile a java program named `daikon`.It needs Java 5.0 (or later) JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and Java 5.0 (or later) compiler. I'm not sure I installed them properly and I should set environment variables like `JAVA_HOME`. I'm not sure about it,too.
when I make it ,it returns such an error, as I'm not at all familiar with java I need a hint about source of the error. Is it because of the `daikon`'s code or maybe not installed required java packages?
here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Couldn't instrument net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.CachedJarFileCallback$1
    at daikon.dcomp.BuildJDK.translate_classes(BuildJDK.java:351)
    at daikon.dcomp.BuildJDK.main(BuildJDK.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.CachedJarFileCallback$1.public volatile synthetic Object run()
        throws java.lang.Exception 1 0
    at daikon.dcomp.DCInstrument.add_dcomp_arg(DCInstrument.java:4166)
    at daikon.dcomp.DCInstrument.instrument_jdk(DCInstrument.java:624)
    at daikon.dcomp.BuildJDK.processClassFile(BuildJDK.java:387)
    at daikon.dcomp.BuildJDK.translate_classes(BuildJDK.java:349)
    ... 1 more
make[2]: *** [dcomp_rt.jar] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/***/***/***/daikonparent/daikon/java'
make[1]: *** [java/dcomp_rt.jar] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/***/***//daikonparent/daikon'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Not entirely sure to be honest, but it looks to be more of a problem with the BuildJDK.

Comment: if you mean there's something wrong with the code. I compile it successfully on fedora.because daikon isn't compatible with kernel 3 I have to switch to debian!

Comment: Previously, Daikon's C front end was not compatible with recent versions of the Linux kernel.  However, Daikon itself and its Java front end (which you seem to be trying to build in the output snippet above) has always been compatible with all versions of Linux.  But, it sounds like you got everything to work on Debian.  Maybe a more recent version of Daikon would now work on Fedora.